# How to "make" a variable that contains another variable value?

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, ping

I'm back to (very modest) scripting after 20+ years outside of that domain.

I'd like to write a small script that pings some IP addresses (some internal and wired, some internal over CPL, some external) to troubleshoot the instability of my network connectivity.

I do a single ping to each host, and if it's down, it adds a line to a file named host_.txt

I don't need alerting, just logging.

I've read many posts here, and my current script was leaning towards the below.

As you can see, I'm storing 2 (stupid and fake for now) IPs in variables $IP1 and $IP2.
I don't want to duplicate the code for each ping, so I basically wanted to encapsulate it in a "for" loop and use the value of the "i" counter to point to the correct variable ( IP$i would then give me IP1, IP2, ...).

My problems/questions:

1. If I concatenate "IP" with $i, I end up with the name of my variable: IP1, IP2, ... but how can I refer to the value of this variable?
2. More in general, is this "while true" a good method to have the script running continuously, as "ping" would do without its "-c" parameter? Won't it use too much resources on my small Raspberry Pi?
3. Would it be better to consider building a list or a table of IPs, and go through that list without requiring the storage of IPs into separate variables?

Any other recommendations are most welcome!

Many thanks

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                                                              IP1=127.0.0.1 IP2=127.0.0.2 while true do
    stamp=$(date +"%Y%m%d-%T")
    for i in $(seq 1 2)
    do
        target=IP$i
        ping -c1 -W10 $target
        if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then echo $target "KO at" $stamp > host_$IP$i.txt ; else echo $IP$i "OK > at" $stamp ; fi
    done
    sleep 1 done
```

For info, I also tried this, without success..

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                                                             
IP1="127.0.0.1"
i=1
echo IP$i
echo $(echo "IP";echo $i)
```

EDIT: For the sake of documentation, with focus on the initial issue: "If I concatenate "IP" with $i, I end up with the name of my variable: IP1, IP2, ... but how can I refer to the value of this variable?"

This technique is called "indirect" and is documented in stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info

My solution was simply to do this:

```
for i in $(seq 1 2)
do
target="IP"$i
echo "${!target}"
#I can then do smth like ping -c1 -W10 ${!target}
done
```

Hope this helps others!

Comment: Each Stack Overflow question should be about _one_ underlying technical question. For example, the `IP$i` part is answered by our existing Q&A about "dynamic" or "indirect" variables in bash

Comment: Also on that topic see [BashFAQ #6](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006). Mind, in this case you're better off with just an array: `ips=( 1.2.3.4 5.6.7.8 ); for ip in "${ips[@]}"; do echo "Checking $ip" >&2; : "do stuff here"; done` -- you can also refer to individual elements as `"${ip[0]}"` and `"${ip[1]}"`

Comment: (also, avoid `seq` -- it's nonstandard, you pay a performance cost to start it, and the shell has builtins that are just as capable as long as you're dealing with integers -- and if you _aren't_ dealing with integers you can't trust seq to behave in a reliable/portable way anyhow, since not all implementations support floating point values)

Comment: (also, when adding code, format it as code -- `> ` is for quoting _text_; put three backticks above and below any code segment to ensure your content is syntax-highlighted and otherwise formatted as source code)

Comment: Shell programming hasn't advanced in the last 20 years (or even 30 years for that matter).  Re-learning it is almost certainly a waste of time.  If you want to learn something useful, modern, and powerful, learn Python.  If you must learn shell then learn how to use [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/).  It can identify many common problems with shell code.  The report that it produces includes links to more information about the problems and how to fix them.  It's a good idea to run [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) on all new and modified shell code.

Comment: See also [The S.O. Bash Info Page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info) . Good luck.

Comment: For the sake of documentation, with focus on the initial issue:

"If I concatenate "IP" with $i, I end up with the name of my variable: IP1, IP2, ... but how can I refer to the value of this variable?"

This technique is called "indirect" and is documented in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info

My solution was simply to do this:

```
    for i in $(seq 1 2)
    do
       target="IP"$i
        echo "${!target}"
#I can then do smth like        ping -c1 -W10 ${!target}                                                                                    
    done
```